# What does it mean an $\bf{isolated \; point}$ for a map defined on a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, transversality

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f : M \to M$ a $C^k$ diffeomorphism.

1) What does it mean an $\bf{isolated \; point}$ for $f$?

2) Why are the transverse fixed points isolated?

Thank you!

Comment: "Isolated point for $f$" makes no sense. You need an isolated point of a subset of $M$. :) So "isolated fixed point" is just fine — the subset is the locus of fixed points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f:M \to M$ a $C^{k}$ difeomorphism.

1. A fixed point $p$ of $f$ is *isolated* if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $p$ is the only fixed point of $f$ in $U$.
2. A fixed point $p$ of $f$ is *transverse* if the graph of $f$ in $M \times M$ is transverse to the diagonal
   $$
   \Delta = \{(p, q) \in M \times M : p = q\},
   $$
   namely if $df(p) - I$ is non-singular. In this event, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that in $U \times U$, the graph of $f$ intersects the diagonal of $f$ precisely at $(p, p)$; that is, $p$ is the unique fixed point of $f$ in $U$.

Comment: Can you recommend me some books or lectures where transversality is explained with more details? Thank you!

Comment: _Differential Topology_ by Guillemin and Pollack was a standard (and well-written) undergraduate-level reference in my student days. _Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint_ by Milnor is another, but though excellent, perhaps a bit less user-friendly.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation for the second question. Can you give me more details? Thank you!

Comment: My oops...that second claim is not OK. Will fix when I have a moment.

Comment: I have one last question : why $p$ is transverse is equivalent with $df(p) - I$ is non-singular? Thank you!

Comment: Some authors may _define_ a "transverse fixed point" by "$df(p) - I$ is non-singular", but in any case: If $\phi:M \to M$ is a map, the tangent space to the graph at $(p, \phi(p))$ is the graph of $d\phi(p)$. Consequently, $df(p) - I$ is non-singular at a fixed point $p$ of $f$ if and only if the graphs of $df(p)$ and $dI(p)$ span $T_{p}M \oplus T_{p}M$, if and only if the graph of $f$ and the diagonal $\Delta$ are transverse at $(p, p)$.